# Retry mechanism for NET Isolated Durable Azure Functions

Tags: azure-durable-functions, .net-7.0

I am migrating a NET6-based in-process function app to a NET7-based isolated function app. It uses Durable Functions, which have changed quite a bit in its API. I need to call an activity function that needs to be retried if the error message contains a `keyword`.

Previously, with 5 retries, 5 mins apart, this was:

```cs
var retryOptionsOld = new RetryOptions(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), 5)
{
    Handle = ex => ex.Message.Contains("KEYWORD")
};
await ctx.CallActivityWithRetryAsync("activityName", null, retryOptionsOld)
```

Now, we need to pass `TaskOptions` to the activity function. However, I don't seem to be able to pass an error message condition AND a time limit condition at the same time. It seems that I can only do one or the other.

```cs
var retryOptionsNew1 = TaskOptions.FromRetryHandler(ctx => ctx.LastFailure.ErrorMessage.Contains("KEYWORD"));
var retryOptionsNew2 = TaskOptions.FromRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy(5, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)));

await ctx.CallActivityAsync("activityName", null, retryOptionsNew1); //or...New2
```

How can I build something like before, combining time parameters and a handler condition?

Comment: Have you tried chaining them? `TaskOptions.FromRetryHandler(...).FromRetryPolicy(...);`

Comment: This does not work unfortunately. `Member 'TaskOptions.FromRetryPolicy(RetryPolicy)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead csharp(CS0176)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the constructor of `TaskOptions` that takes the `RetryPolicy`.

```cs
var retryPolicy= new RetryPolicy(
    maxNumberOfAttempts: 3, 
    firstRetryInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
{
    HandleAsync = c => Task.FromResult(c.Message.StartsWith("err"))
};
var taskOptions = new TaskOptions(retryPolicy);
```

Comment: Unfortunately `HandleAsync` isn't used by Durable Functions. See [CallActivityAsync](https://github.com/microsoft/durabletask-dotnet/blob/215eeb8ba7652a8d4cf28c80fcbb6af14aa19304/src/Worker/Core/Shims/TaskOrchestrationContextWrapper.cs#L93) and [ToDurableTaskCoreRetryOptions](https://github.com/microsoft/durabletask-dotnet/blob/215eeb8ba7652a8d4cf28c80fcbb6af14aa19304/src/Shared/Core/RetryPolicyExtensions.cs#L18).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it in isolated functions.
I create extensions and just pass in a retry policy or the max attempts.

```
public static async Task<T> CallActivityWithRetryAsync<T>(
    this TaskOrchestrationContext context, string name, object parm,
    int maxAttempts, TimeSpan? firstRetryInterval = null)
{
     RetryPolicy policy = new RetryPolicy(maxAttempts, firstRetryInterval ?? TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
     return await context.CallActivityAsync<T>(name, parm, new TaskOptions { Retry = policy });
}

public static async Task CallActivityWithRetryAsync(
    this TaskOrchestrationContext context, string name, object parm,
    int maxAttempts, TimeSpan? firstRetryInterval = null)
{
     RetryPolicy policy = new RetryPolicy(maxAttempts, firstRetryInterval ?? TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
     await context.CallActivityAsync(name, parm, new TaskOptions { Retry = policy });
}
public static async Task<T> CallActivityWithRetryAsync<T>(
    this TaskOrchestrationContext context,
    string name, object parm, RetryPolicy policy)
{
    return await context.CallActivityAsync<T>(name, parm, new TaskOptions { Retry = policy });
}

public static async Task CallActivityWithRetryAsync(
    this TaskOrchestrationContext context,
    string name, object parm, RetryPolicy policy)
{
    await context.CallActivityAsync(name, parm, new TaskOptions { Retry = policy });
}
```